# In Rails, how do I filter a controller using a parameter in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view that cycles through some companies. With each company I want to cycle through some timeline-posts specific to each company. How do I pass the parameter as to which company I am on to the timeline controller? Or is that not the correct way to do that?

```
# controllers/companies_controller.rb
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @companies = Company.sorted
    @timelines = Timeline.sorted
    ...

# models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timelines, dependent: :destroy
  scope :sorted, lambda { order("companies.name ASC") }
  ...

# models/timeline.rb
class Timeline < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  scope :sorted, lambda { order("timelines.created_at DESC")}
  ...

# views/companies/index.html.erb
<% @companies.each_with_index do |company, index| %>
  ...
  <% @timelines.each do |timeline| %>
```

That last line is where I am having trouble. I can get all the timeline posts to show up this way, but I want to make them specific to the company in each iteration. I have `company.id` available in the first loop, but I'm not sure how to use it since it is in a view.

Notes: I have a foreign key in `timelines` referencing `company_id`. Versions: `ruby 2.2.3` and `rails 4.2.4`

Comment: You have has_many relationship between Company  and Timeline so if  you want timeline post for specific company you can do like this <% companytimelines.each do |timeline| %>  in your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this one

```
<% @companies.each_with_index do |company, index| %>
  ...
  <% company.timelines.each do |timeline| %>
```

**update:**

in addition to pavan's comment for the sorted feature you should add the `sorted` scope to the `timelines` like this one

```
<% @companies.each_with_index do |company, index| %>
  ...
  <% company.timelines.sorted.each do |timeline| %>
```

Comment: I figured it was something "simple". That worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below

```
<% @companies.each_with_index do |company, index| %>
  ...
  <% @timelines.where(comapany_id: company.id).each do |timeline| %>
```

assuming the second loop is inside the first loop.

Comment: This worked too, but I like the simplicity of the other one above. Thanks.

Comment: @Reveren I posted this answer keeping in mind that you want `timelines` in a descending order as you have `@timelines = Timeline.sorted`. The other answer doesn't give the `timelines` in descending order.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Thanks for the clarification. That is important.

Comment: ah didn't see the `sorted`. but you can add the sorted in the association `company.timelines.sorted`. i update my answer